# Application.AdvancedSearch syntax issues

Tags: vba, outlook

I was wondering how to fix this Outlook *Advanced Search* SQL-like criteria string:

```
filterStr = "@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:subject"" = """ & _
            EmailName & """ AND ""urn:schemas:httpmail:date"" >= """ & _
            TDateUTC & """ AND ""urn:schemas:httpmail:date"" <= """ & _
            TDateUTCEOD & """"
```

- `EmailName` is a string variable which calls an email subject
- `TDateUTC` is a date variable which calls an input date and then
  converts it to UTC
- `TDateUTCEOD` is the above but with the time set to 11:59:59pm

My syntax is completely broken because I have no idea how to incorporate variables into an *Advanced Search* for Outlook VBA.

Comment: Not sure what most of this means, sorry. I'm basically trying to filter an Outlook inbox to display items in between two times and then search by email name, get the SentOn date, and then paste the SentOn date to another spreadsheet.

The reason for this is because there are daily emails with the same name and I need to copy the SentOn date for an inputted date. Right now my code just takes the most recent email's SentOn datetime; I'm trying to filter my inbox using AdvancedSearch and SQL but my syntax is wrong.

Comment: Well, AdvancedSearch in VBA can't take anything other than SQL which is why I tagged this as such. I also tagged VBA and Excel VBA.

Comment: You're using the Outlook object model, "Excel" is as irrelevant as "SQL". I've edited your question to remove tags from the title, more precisely name things, and use tags that are appropriate for the API involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866933.aspx) examples for programmatically performing an *Advanced Search* shows the proper syntax:

> ```vb
> Const strF As String = "urn:schemas:mailheader:subject = 'Test'"
> ```

Notice:

- The `urn:schemas:foo:bar` part is **not** surrounded by double quotes.
- Field values are surrounded by **single quotes**.
- MSDN makes no mention of a `@SQL=` prefix.

This means a proper criteria string would look like this:

```vb
filterStr = "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject = '" & EmailName & _
      "' AND urn:schemas:httpmail:date >= '" & TDateUTC & _
      "' AND urn:schemas:httpmail:date <= '" & TDateUTCEOD & '"
```

Note that this will implicitly convert `TDateUTC` and `TDateUTCEOD` to a `String` value if they're `Date` variables. You could make that conversion explicit using the built-in `CStr` conversion function:

```vb
filterStr = "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject = '" & EmailName & _
      "' AND urn:schemas:httpmail:date >= '" & CStr(TDateUTC) & _
      "' AND urn:schemas:httpmail:date <= '" & CStr(TDateUTCEOD) & '"
```

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. Used this: filterStr = "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject = '" & EmailName & "' AND urn:schemas:httpmail:date >= '" & TDateUTC & "' AND urn:schemas:httpmail:date <= '" & TDateUTCEOD & "' "